# GulpFile not Generating CSS Files

Tags: gulp

I am starting with a new project and want to have Gulp compile my SASS into CSS. I just started out easy and have tried for a whole to create CSS files, the issue is that there are no files being generated in the CSS folder. I have a SASS folder , and CSS folder.

This is my Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var input = './sass/**/*.scss';
var output = './css';

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp
    // Find all `.scss` files from the `stylesheets/` folder
    .src(input)
    // Run Sass on those files
    .pipe(sass())
    // Write the resulting CSS in the output folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(output));
});
```

Comment: hi maybe try to put  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))

Comment: Any error in the console after put it??

Comment: You are running your gulp with `gulp sass`, right? Because if you don't provide any parameter it tries to find `default` task, but in that case you would get error...

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing `SASS` or `SCSS`? Because the extension of the `input` pattern that you shared ends with `.scss`, 'pure' Sass files (ending in `.sass`) are not caught by the rule.